# how do i select the sibling of an input field

Tags: jquery, validation, siblings

Alright so I've been making an attempt at this for a while now. My logic seems correct in my eyes but there must be something that I am missing. Here is my code:

the html:

```
<div class="login-input-wrap">
    <h3>First Name:</h3>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" />
</div>
```

the javascript with some jquery

```
function validateSignUp()
{
    var fname = $('input [name|="firstname"]');
    if (fname.val() == "" || fname.val() == null)
    {
        fname.parent().children('h3').css("color", "red");
        alert ("here it is");
    }
    return false;
}
```

validate gets called when the form is submitted, the alert is being called but the css isn't working. I also tried selecting the sibling of the input like this:

```
function validateSignUp()
{
    var fname = $('input [name|="firstname"]');
    if (fname.val() == "" || fname.val() == null)
    {
        fname.siblings('h3').css("color", "red");
        alert ("here it is");
    }
    return false;
}
```

but that didn't work either.

thanks for any help.

Comment: Could the problem be the poorly formed `h3` tag? missing the leading `<`.  It should be `<h3>` instead of `h3>`.

Comment: no that's just an error in me posting it, ill fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space after `input` in this selector.  There must be no spaces between things that all apply to the same object.  You were not correctly selecting the `input` tag so an empty jQuery object had no siblings so the rest didn't work.  Change this:

```
$('input [name|="firstname"]')
```

so it looks like this:

```
$('input[name|="firstname"]')
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/YyUAx/

---

You can also simplify this:

```
if (fname.val() == "" || fname.val() == null)
```

by changing it to this:

```
if (!fname.val()) {
```

Comment: gotta love when a space is what messes things up, thank you very much.  seems as though the | is not necessary though, does it matter?

Comment: @CraigDykstra - I don't know why you used `|=` instead of `=`.  `|=` would also match `firstname2` and `myfirstname` so it depends upon whether you want an `exact` match or a `contains` match.

Comment: was just taking code from the jquery api, probably didnt read it correctly though. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
​$("input").prev("h3").css("color","red")​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

to get the previous element

edit : with the markup shown ,

```
​$("input[name=firstname]").prev("h3").css("color","red")​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

still works

Comment: For their markup, this generates no different answer than what they already have.

Comment: ​$("input[name=firstname]").prev("h3").css("color","red")​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ works

Comment: i see that it does, and i may eventually use this, but when i change my var decloration to $("input[name=firstname]") and then use the variable to set the css it doesnt work.  but i know that it is getting in the if statement cause i put an alert in there, so the .val() is working in the if

Comment: @CraigDykstra - see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9917782/816620).  The problem was earlier in your jQuery where you weren't selecting the input tag properly.